# notifyItemRemoved() is not updating my recycler view but removes data from the array list

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am using a recycler view. I've set an OnLongClickListener() on it using a custom interface. everything works fine but when I long-press the row the app crashes with Java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException. while debugging I found that my array list's data is being deleted while I long-press but the recycler view is just not getting updated.
here's my code.

MainActivity.java

```
package com.raunak.alarmdemo4;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.DividerItemDecoration;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.ActivityInfo;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Switch;
import android.widget.Toast;
import com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton;
import com.raunak.alarmdemo4.Activities.AddAlarm;
import com.raunak.alarmdemo4.Adapters.AlarmAdapter;
import com.raunak.alarmdemo4.HelperClasses.AlarmsDBhelperClass;
import com.raunak.alarmdemo4.Interfaces.AlarmRecyclerViewInterface;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements AlarmRecyclerViewInterface {

    FloatingActionButton mAlarmAddButton;
    RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
    SQLiteDatabase db;
    AlarmsDBhelperClass mAlarmsDBhelperClass;
    ArrayList<String> nameArrayList,modeArrayList,repeatArrayList,hoursArrayList,minArrayList;
    Switch mSwitch;
    AlarmAdapter alarmAdapter = new AlarmAdapter(hoursArrayList,minArrayList,modeArrayList,repeatArrayList,nameArrayList,this);

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);

        //Initializing RecyclerView & DatabaseHelperClass and the FAB button
        mAlarmsDBhelperClass = new AlarmsDBhelperClass(getApplicationContext());
        mAlarmAddButton = findViewById(R.id.btnAlarmADD);
        mRecyclerView = findViewById(R.id.alarmList);
        mSwitch = findViewById(R.id.switchONOFF);


        //Initializing ArrayList
        nameArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
        modeArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
        repeatArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
        hoursArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
        minArrayList = new ArrayList<>();

        DividerItemDecoration itemDecoration = new DividerItemDecoration(this,DividerItemDecoration.VERTICAL);
        mRecyclerView.addItemDecoration(itemDecoration);

        //Getting a writable reference of the Database.
        db = mAlarmsDBhelperClass.getWritableDatabase();
        //getAlarm(db);
        getAlarm(db);
        mAlarmAddButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.addalarm);
        mAlarmAddButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent mIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), AddAlarm.class);
                startActivity(mIntent);
            }
        });

       /* mSwitch.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean b) {
                if(b){
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Checked !",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }else{
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Unchecked !",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });*/
        AlarmAdapter alarmAdapter = new AlarmAdapter(hoursArrayList,minArrayList,modeArrayList,repeatArrayList,nameArrayList,this);
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext()));
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(alarmAdapter);
        mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    }

    public void getAlarm(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM alarms", new String[]{});
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        if (cursor != null) {
            do {
                nameArrayList.add(cursor.getString(2));
                modeArrayList.add(cursor.getString(3));
                repeatArrayList.add(cursor.getString(4));
                hoursArrayList.add(Integer.toString(cursor.getInt(5)));
                minArrayList.add(Integer.toString(cursor.getInt(6)));
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }
        cursor.close();
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(int position) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Alarm Clicked !", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onLongItemClick(int position) {

        hoursArrayList.remove(position);
        Log.d("d",""+position);
        alarmAdapter.notifyItemRemoved(position);
        Toast.makeText(this, ""+hoursArrayList.size(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

my Recyclerview adapter.

```
package com.raunak.alarmdemo4.Adapters;

import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;
import com.raunak.alarmdemo4.Interfaces.AlarmRecyclerViewInterface;
import com.raunak.alarmdemo4.R;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class AlarmAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<AlarmAdapter.AlarmView> {
    //Variables for the main recycler view
    private ArrayList<String> hoursArrayList;
    private ArrayList<String> minArrayList;
    private ArrayList<String> modeArrayList;
    private ArrayList<String> repeatArrayList;
    private ArrayList<String> nameArrayList;
    private AlarmRecyclerViewInterface mInterface;

    public AlarmAdapter(ArrayList<String> hours,ArrayList<String> mins,ArrayList<String> mode,ArrayList<String> repeat,ArrayList<String> name,AlarmRecyclerViewInterface mInterface){
        this.hoursArrayList = hours;
        this.minArrayList = mins;
        this.modeArrayList = mode;
        this.nameArrayList = name;
        this.repeatArrayList = repeat;
        this.mInterface = mInterface;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public AlarmView onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
        View view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.alarm_profile,parent,false);
        return new AlarmView(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull AlarmView holder, int position) {
        if(Integer.parseInt(hoursArrayList.get(position)) < 10 ){
            holder.hours.setText("0"+hoursArrayList.get(position));
        }else {
            holder.hours.setText(hoursArrayList.get(position));
        }
        if (Integer.parseInt(minArrayList.get(position)) < 10){
            holder.mins.setText("0"+minArrayList.get(position));
        }else {
            holder.mins.setText(minArrayList.get(position));
        }
        holder.repeat.setText(repeatArrayList.get(position));
        holder.mode.setText(modeArrayList.get(position));
        holder.name.setText(nameArrayList.get(position));
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return nameArrayList.size();
    }

    /*ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback itemTouchHelperCallback = new ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback(0,ItemTouchHelper.RIGHT) {
        @Override
        public boolean onMove(@NonNull RecyclerView recyclerView, @NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, @NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder target) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public void onSwiped(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int direction) {
            nameArrayList.remove(viewHolder.getAdapterPosition());
            modeArrayList.remove(viewHolder.getAdapterPosition());
            repeatArrayList.remove(viewHolder.getAdapterPosition());
            hoursArrayList.remove(viewHolder.getAdapterPosition());
            minArrayList.remove(viewHolder.getAdapterPosition());
        }
    };*/

    public class AlarmView extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        TextView hours,mins,repeat,name,mode;
        public AlarmView(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            hours = itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtHOUR);
            mins = itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtMins);
            repeat = itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtRepeatDays);
            name = itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtName);
            mode = itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtMode);

            itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    Log.d("d",""+getAdapterPosition());
                    mInterface.onItemClick(getAdapterPosition());
                }
            });

            itemView.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onLongClick(View view) {
                    Log.d("d",""+getAdapterPosition());
                    mInterface.onLongItemClick(getAdapterPosition());
                    return true;
                }
            });

        }
    }

}
```

my CustomInterface

```
package com.raunak.alarmdemo4.Interfaces;

public interface AlarmRecyclerViewInterface {
    void onItemClick(int position);
    void onLongItemClick(int position);

}
```

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should remove the element also from nameArrayList and inside your Adapter:

```
@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return nameArrayList.size();   //This return a number that is higher than the number of elements
}
```

.

```
//When you call this, you remove the element from the list in the Main Activity, but not in your Adapter
hoursArrayList.remove(position);
```

.

```
itemView.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onLongClick(View view) {
                int pos = getAdapterPosition();
                Log.d("d",""+ pos);
                hoursArrayList.remove(pos);    //I think you'd add
                nameArrayList.remove(pos);     //these two lines
                mInterface.onLongItemClick(pos);
                return true;
            }
        });
```

.

```
@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return hoursArrayList.size();     //Or just the first line and modify this
}
```

And you should modify your MainActiivty fields:

```
FloatingActionButton mAlarmAddButton;
RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
SQLiteDatabase db;
AlarmsDBhelperClass mAlarmsDBhelperClass;
ArrayList<String> nameArrayList,modeArrayList,repeatArrayList,hoursArrayList,minArrayList;
Switch mSwitch;
AlarmAdapter alarmAdapter = new AlarmAdapter(hoursArrayList,minArrayList,modeArrayList,repeatArrayList,nameArrayList,this);  
//This line has nosense, if you re-declare another alarmAdapter in the onCreate
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, sir! but I realized the problem was just with the getItemCount(), so in the getItemCount() I replaced the nameArraylist.size(); with hoursArrayList.size(); or with one we remove in the onLongClickListener in the mainActivity.

Answer (score 1):

Your are declaring and assigning different adapter in onCreate. Remove the declaration from there and just initialize it there.

```
AlarmAdapter alarmAdapter = new AlarmAdapter(hoursArrayList,minArrayList,modeArrayList,repeatArrayList,nameArrayList,this);
```

And you need to improve your code for efficiency, create a model class instead of declaring arrrayList of every param.

Comment: I'm a beginner but thanks for the tip, will definitely try this one out.